# How to separate routes from index.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to separate my routes to a separate file using the following code in index.js:

```
import routes from './routes';
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router routes={routes}/>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

my routes.js looks like this:

```
export default (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>
        <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductContainer}/>
        <Route path="/products/:productId" component={AddProductComponent}/>
    </Switch>
);
```

For some reason my page appears blank with this code.

It works perfectly fine if I just wrap all routes inside index.js like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>
                <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductContainer}/>
                <Route path="/products/:productId" component={AddProductComponent}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I would keep it like this, but I would also want to separate into a single file route handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Router` is just a React component that allows for `children` prop. Render your routes as a component:

```
import Routes from './routes';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here a sample working codesandbox to play: https://codesandbox.io/s/ywvn59y7rj

Comment: Its not working, I am getting this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: should I change anything on routes.js?

Answer (score 2):

More detailed answer, changing routes.js to

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>
                <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductContainer}/>
                <Route path="/products/:productId" component={AddProductComponent}/>
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
 export default Routes;
```

and changing index.js to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Routes/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

worked perfectly fine. I hope this would help anybody

Comment: looks great but I would still prefer storing routes in a JSON like way

Answer (score 0):

Another option wich is easier to maintain is storing routes as JSON like objects in an array and then loop over them.

routes.js

```
import AppComponent from 'xxx'
export default const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: AppComponent,
    exact: true
  }
  // and so on
]
```

index.js

```
import routes from './routes';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      {routes.map({path, component, exact} => (
        <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={component}/>
      )}
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: for some reason this does not seem for me most convenient approach, why not handle it in a more abstract way, using Routes component?

Comment: as your app grows it will help you to keep track of all routes easier, especially if you work in a team. It is also easier to implement things like code splitting and server side redering or extend your routing system with other things.